# NSInternalInconsistencyException - Deleting a row based on CGPoint position

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So I have a sliding UITableViewCell with a drawer of buttons. Per another user I was directed to a pretty nice implementation to get the indexPath of the UITableViewCell. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when I'm trying to delete the row. The object *does* delete successfully though.

```
-(void)checkButtonWasTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        PFObject *object = [self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post the error here?   Does your `-deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:` call the supplied block on the main thread?  (It should for GUI work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Parse, which is a really nice service, IMO.  The `deleteInBackground:` takes care of the cloud delete, but you haven't done the delete from your local array backing the table.  Try adding the line:

```
[self.listArray removeObject:object];
```

right after you get the `PFObject *object`.  If it's not a mutable array, then you'll need a little extra code:

```
NSMutableArray *changeMyArray = [self.listArray mutableCopy];  // assume you're using ARC
[changeMyArray removeObject:object];
self.listArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:changeMyArray];
```

Also, since the local delete is happening fast and synchronously, you needn't do the table update in the completion block of the cloud delete.  Just place it inline...

```
    PFObject *object = [self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.listArray removeObject:object];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
    }];
```

Comment: oh snap, you're right. Doh. Thanks @danh. Also I agree, parse has been a lifesaver for me.

Comment: one more edit.  the reload data after the endUpdates kind of defeats the purpose of the animated table updates.  you can drop that.